# camel cdi, lookup datasource provided by glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, apache-camel, jndi, cdi

I managed to get camel working with its CDI module, but I'm unable to register datasources in the registry. I basically have a sql route that looks like this:

```
sql:SELECT * FROM INBOX_DFEP WHERE id > :#lastID?dataSource=jdbc/DFEP
```

my application server is glassfish 4, and I've registered a jdbc resource with that name, as I usually do with JPA. Anyway camel does not seems to be able to lookup that datasource for me.

```
org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: jdbc/DFEP of type: javax.sql.DataSource
```

what am I doing wrong? how do I register a datasource in the camel registry using CDI?

Comment: Is the glashfish registry available using JNDI from a client? It could be a matter of having camel-cdi fallback to use JNDi if its not found in the CDI registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/DFEP")
private javax.sql.DataSource datasource;

@Produces
@Named("queryDatasource")
public javax.sql.DataSource getDatasource() {
    return datasource;
}

}
```

After that you only have to change your toute to:

sql:SELECT * FROM INBOX_DFEP WHERE id > :#lastID?dataSource=queryDatasource